# Copy pasting does not work in nitrous webIDE?

Tags: nitrousio

I cannot paste code into the webIDE console. copy pasting works all around the IDE except the console. Is there a way to fix this?
please help, its so annoying!

Answer (score 33):

If you're on Windows you'll need to hit **Control + Shift + V** to paste in the console on the Nitrous.IO Web IDE.

Comment: That's very annoying.  Is there some reason the _normal_ CTRL/V can't be used?

Comment: This is only true in Chrome; it doesn't work in Firefox -- you have to use the Paste option in the menu bar.

Comment: press alt to see menu bar in FF

Answer (score 3):

The added support was mentioned [on their changelog](http://updates.nitrous.io/2013/05/24/changelog-may-24-2013.html).  In a nutshell:

- cmd+c and cmd+v support for copy and paste in mac
- ctrl+shift+v support to paste in chrome, paste using menu bar in firefox *(Edit => Paste)*

Answer (score 0):

There is no Edit -> Paste in Firefox 35 on Windows 8.1 in the Web IDE, and, as always, control-V and control-shift-V do nothing.

Comment: This look like a comment.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 8.1 you can get Edit -> Paste option in Firefox if you press Alt.