# Nitrous.IO how to copy from console (windows, chrome browser)

Tags: nitrousio

I can copy/paste just fine from Nitrous.IO editor windows.
I can also paste into console (Shift + Cntl + V).
How can I copy a line from the console?  Shift + Cntl + C does not work and there is no Copy entry in the menu.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy pasting does not work in nitrous webIDE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17965647/copy-pasting-does-not-work-in-nitrous-webide)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too simple...
Use standard Ctl-C to copy text from NitrousIO console and use Shift-Ctl-V to paste text into NitrousIO console.

Answer (score 0):

`Shift + Control + C` is the designated keyboard shortcut for copying in windows (according to the [support documentation](http://help.nitrous.io/ide-shortcuts/)).

If that is not working then there may be a browser compatibility issue. Contact the support team with your Browser/OS details and they will be able to do some testing.

Comment: Yeah, well I can get to the string from developer tools 'Elements',  and also once I highlighted a console line, right-clicked and got a 'Copy' in the context menu.  Just hoped NitrousIO folks had provided ability to copy text from console using some keyboard combination...